# Difference between Play Framework Session and PHP Session

Tags: session, cookies, playframework, stateless, stateful

if I understand correctly, the Play Framework uses cookies to store the whole session, while PHP just stores a Session-ID in a cookie and saves the real session itself on the server-side.

The Play Framework promotes good horizontal scalability with its approach. But I do not see the advantage, if I use any other framework and save my session into a database, for example with Symfony and Redis.

So how is the Play Framework better (for some use cases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial idea behind Play's architecture is that the designers wanted it to be stateless ie. no data being maintained between requests on the server-side - this is why it does not follow the servlet spec. This opens up flexibility with things like scalability as you have mentioned - this is in itself a big advantage if your application is large enough that it needs to scale across more than a single machine - managing server-side session data across a cluster is a pain.

But of course, anything other than a trivial application, Will have a need to maintain some session data and as you have mentioned yourself you would usually do this with a cache or DB. The cookie session Play uses is restricted to about 4Kb so is only intended for a relatively small amount of data.

The benefits of a stateless architecture are manyfold and are what Play's architecture is designed to exploit.

A bit dated but the relevancy still applies in this [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/stateful-web-applications-that-scale-lik/208403462).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can still not see the advantage, since also with Play you usually have to also use the database approach because of security concerns with the session (?)

Comment: No probs. and sessions are used so widely in web applications/frameworks that I think you could have a long debate about whether they should be used or not and whether one approach is better than another. I think Play's decision not to use server session is partly born out of creator Guillaume Bort's annoyance with Enterprise Java libraries like the Servlet API (see - http://guillaumebort.tumblr.com/post/558830013/why-there-is-no-servlets-in-play). One notable benefit of not using session is hot reload.

Comment: Thank you again! :) Let me rephrase my question: Why would anyone store the session in the memory and not in the database (except maybe for performance reasons)? In regards to the article linked in your main answer it seems that an NoSQL-Database for example would be perfectly fine as a session store.

Comment: Well you answered your own question really - performance. Transacting with a Database is very expensive, whereas a main memory reference is many orders of magnitude quicker. Mileage varies with the architecture of course but the main point holds true. In-memory cache is quicker than DB of course, and when people talk about stateless architecture, they very often mean they are caching data between requests rather using sessions.